# How can I use VTK along with Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vtk

I am trying to build an interactive program using Unity3D. I need some functions from VTK to deal with some CAE data, like contours, isosurfaces, clipping etc. But how can I put them together?

How can I get its vertex buffer and index buffer or something alike produced by its mappers (or props?), and rebuild meshes in Unity3D? Is this way slow? (e.g. when I dynamically adjust clipping plane on runtime, will rebuilding meshes be a problem?)

Or is there a more elegant way to do that?